# Table with multi rows and columns

Tags: tables, multirow, multicolumn

I can do the table in figure:
[image: table]
I wrote this code but I can not fix the left and bottom side.

```
\documentclass{tufte-handout}

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{booktabs} 

\begin{document}
    \begin{fullwidth}
        \begin{center}
            \begin{tabular}{lccc}
                \toprule
                \multirow{2}*{Elemento} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{FUNZIONI TRASCENDENTI} \\
                \cmidrule(lr){2-4}
                & LOGARITMICHE & ESPONENZIALI & LOGARITMICHE \\
                \midrule

                \bottomrule
            \end{tabular}
        \end{center}
    \end{fullwidth}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I can't see the exact relationship between the figure and your code. You have 4 columns, and the figure has up to 10. Where should your cells go in the figure?

Comment: @Bernard the cells go in the bottom

Comment: In which columns? You have 4 cells and there are 10 columns.

Comment: @Bernard Two in the left zone and three in the right                              I edit the post, I had forgotten a small piece of code, I'm sorry

Comment: But *where*  do your texts go? You can post a hand sketch to make it clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**edit:**

- it seems that on the answer forgot as op as well me :-(.
- today i recognized, that the loaded *mwe* is not complete ... and that  [CarLaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/101651/carlatex) ask me in her comment (which seems that i overlooked). i'm very sorry for this.
- now i add missing part of *mwe*: : `\begin{document}`, `\begin{fullwidth}` and definitions of used lengths,
- beside this i add `showframe` package to for show page layout (which had to be removed in real document)

now *mwe* works as expected (tested).

[image]

```
\documentclass{tufte-handout}

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{booktabs,tabularx}
    \newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}    
\newlength\lengtha % width of two-columm multicolumn
\newlength\lengthb % width of four-columm multicolumn
\newlength\lengthc % width of six-columm multicolumn
%
\setlength\aboverulesep{0pt}
\setlength\belowrulesep{0pt}

%-------------------------------- show page layout, only for test
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}
\begin{fullwidth}
\setlength\lengtha{\dimexpr.2\hsize+2\tabcolsep-2\arrayrulewidth\relax}
\setlength\lengthb{\dimexpr.4\hsize+6\tabcolsep-4\arrayrulewidth\relax}
\setlength\lengthc{\dimexpr.6\hsize+10\tabcolsep-6\arrayrulewidth\relax}
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|*{10}{C|} }
    \toprule
\multicolumn{4}{|P{\lengthb}|}{Elemento}
                &   \multicolumn{6}{P{\lengthc}|}{FUNZIONI TRASCENDENTI}    \\
    \midrule
\multicolumn{2}{|P{\lengtha}|}{?}
    &   \multicolumn{2}{P{\lengtha}|}{?}
        &   \multicolumn{2}{P{\lengtha}|}{LOGARITMICHE}
            &   \multicolumn{2}{P{\lengtha}|}{ESPONENZIALI}
                &   \multicolumn{2}{P{\lengtha}|}{LOGARITMICHE}    \\
    \midrule
    &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   \\
    \bottomrule
            \end{tabularx}
    \end{fullwidth}
\end{document}
```

Actually I reproduce showed picture of table and text from your MWE place as you can see from above image. I'm not sure if I guess correctly what you like to obtain.

Comment: Zarko, could you explain how the `\length...`s value are assigned?

Comment: @CarLaTeX,  thank you for your comment. it seems that i overlooked it and consequently not respond immediately. i,m very sorry for this. now i found that important part of answer is missing .... now after 7+ moths, i correct this.

Comment: @Ilmionome456, please see my edits of answer. in the first version was missed important part of code. now is corrected.